# How to execute consecutive commands using ssh -t

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, tmux

What I'm trying to do:

`ssh somewhere@ip  -t "tmux && echo 'a'"`

and intention is: 'access to a remote server(ip) and open tmux and echo "a" on that tmux session'.

But what it missed is `echo 'a'`: it prints 'a' in my local machine, not remote server's tmux session (even after I exit the tmux session manually)

How can I do it?

Comment: How about writing `tmux && echo 'a'` to `rfile`, sftp that rfile to `somewhere` and then execute  `sh rfile` on `somewhere`?

Comment: @JeffHolt that could work but my whole goal is to keep tmux session alive after echo

Comment: What I've tried as well: `tmux new -d -s my-session "echo 'a'"` but it keeps killing the session after echoing

Comment: Which shell do you want to execute `echo a`, the shell that started `tmux` or the shell that `tmux` starts?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an expect script to solve your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect


spawn ssh somewhere@ip 

interact {

-o -nobuffer "$"  {
        send "tmux\n"
}

}
```

The above script won't get the job done.  Basically, it will look for a $ in the ssh session output (let's say your prompt ends with a '$') and it will send the characters "tmux" and a linefeed.  That will start your tmux session.  However, you'll have to add an additional case to send the "a\n" to tmux when the tmux session prompts the user interactively.

You may have to play a bit to get `expect` to work for you.  I'm no expert on `expect`, but it may be the right tool for the job.